# Eclipse/Java Mac OS12 .jar file used to run but no longer runs

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, image, jar

I have been rewriting a 100,000 line application from 2009
in modern Java/Eclipse/Mac os12, and there is a problem
with the executable - I have been"exporting" to .jar file
from the Eclipse environment, and have been able to
run the .jar file with java -jar FileName.jar.   A few
weeks ago, (ca Feb 1 2023), the jar files started throwing errors
on startup, saying they were unable to locate what should
have been easily accessible system image files - specifically
lines like these

```
public static Image lineSelectedToolImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/InverseLineSelectTool.GIF"));

public static Image rectangleSelectedToolImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/InverseRectangleSelectTool.GIF"));

public static Image circleSelectedToolImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/InverseCircleSelectTool.GIF"));

public static Image textSelectedToolImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/InverseTextTool.GIF"));
```

I added a folder to the Project Properties Resource/Linked Resources page that contains the required images . . . but this seemed to have no effect.

Thanks to all for any suggestions - my native language is C and I am an embedded systems programmer, so much of the linking things in Eclipse are new to me.

Comment: FWIW, I would never rely on an IDE's native build system. They are simply not reproducible enough. Use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @Michael What exactly is not reproducible when exporting a JAR?

Comment: @howlger At the most basic level, what if I don't have Eclipse installed? What if I prefer to use IntelliJ? How do you expect to run an Eclipse build in a headless environment, like CI? Even if you ignore all of that, IDE configs are usually massive, sprawling XML files, which contain much more than just the build configuration. Checking them into VCS is always a nightmare. There is probably no guarantee the same XML is both forwards and backwards compatible across different versions of the IDE.

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource​(...)` looks weird here. Better include the image as source so they end up in the JAR (are they currently in the JAR?) and load them as `InputStream` via `getResourceAsStream​(...)`.

Comment: @Michael I asked you what exactly is not reproducible when you export a JAR? Of course, you should version control all project-specific settings, not only the Maven or Gradle build file, but that's another thing.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting !  Some more info:  the .jar files used to run, but now they don't, that is what is not reproducible. Howler:  this is instrument control software for a network of 5 telescopes, they never run headless or on anything except our own Mac mini computers.

Comment: Also - any suggestions on how to "include the images as source"?   The image files show up in the .jar file when I list out the contents.

Comment: @howlger And I answered it. I can't reproduce a build without the exact same IDE. In headless environments, that's not just personal preference, that's almost a physical impossibility. Build tools solve this problem. No one serious uses native IDE builds. They're for basic/toy projects.

Comment: Is `ClassLoader.getSystemResource​(...)` part of your code so that you can change it?

Comment: @Michael What you say is not true and makes no sense because an IDE is not a build system. A build script only covers part of the project-specific settings. Using a build system is recommended, but does not help here.

Comment: @howlger Both Eclipse and IntelliJ include their own native build systems. This is what OP is using and what I'm advocating to avoid. Using Maven absolutely would help here because Maven builds are reproducible; Eclipse is garbage.

Comment: @Paul Make sure that the filename case matches down to the letter when you've built the jar file--and of course, that the files are in the jar at all. You should also separate the result of `getSystemResource()` from the `getImage()` call and add some logging or debug output so you have some idea of what's happening at runtime--is the getSystemResource call failing, or is getImage taking a good result and messing up for some reason? Linked Resources are convenient for structuring the project, but I'm not sure that the Jar Export function supports them fully.

Comment: noting - I did as you suggested and separated the lines into

Comment: nitind :     I did as you suggested and separated the lines into the following - sorry the "spelling corrector" changed your name into "noting" . . . public static URL my_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/LineSelectTool.GIF");
 
 public static Image testImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(my_url); and then corrected the CASE of the ".gif" to "GIF" - and now the system loads !!  Thank you so much -

Comment: @Michael Of course this is not related to the tool with which the JAR was created. It is not true that the JAR export is not reliable (JAR is an Java standard even older than Maven and Gradle). It is also not true that the project-specific settings made by Eclipse are version-dependent (in fact, they are more stable than Maven, whose compatibility got broken by switching Maven Central to HTTPS only).